# Null Pointer Exception while trying to use GSON API for json reading

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, gson

Lines of Code:
//Error LINE:
Step trying to read data using method from JsonDataReader Class(Code follows next)

```
public void enter_personal_details_on_checkout_page(String customerFirstName) throws InterruptedException{

    Customer customer=FileReaderManager.getInstance().getJsonDataReader().getCustomerByFirstName(customerFirstName);
    checkoutPage.fill_PersonalDetails(customer);
}
```

JSON Data Reader Class:

```
public class JsonDataReader {
private final String customerFilePath = FileReaderManager.getInstance().getConfigReader().getTestDataResourcePath() + "Customer.json";
private List<Customer> customerList;

public JsonDataReader(){
    customerList = getCustomerData();
}

private List<Customer> getCustomerData() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    try {
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(customerFilePath));
        Customer[] Customer = gson.fromJson(bufferReader, Customer[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(Customer);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Json file not found at path : " + customerFilePath);
    }finally {
        try { if(bufferReader != null) bufferReader.close();}
        catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

My JSON POJO Class:

public class Customer {

```
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public Integer age;
public String emailAddress;
public Address address;
public PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

public class Address {

    public String streetAddress;
    public String city;
    public String postCode;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public String county;

}

public class PhoneNumber {

    public String home;
    public String mob;

}
```

}

Used below steps trying to read the JSON reader:

1. JSON Data set
2. Java POJO class to represent JSON data
3. A JSON Data Reader class

==> Can anyone tell how can i resolve this issue of 'NullPointerException' here?

Comment: Thanks Cid. added Json POJO Class clearly now and deleted my previous comment which has same code.

Comment: Can you also include the stack trace, it might be beneficial.